# question on adding a formcontrol to a form group?

Tags: angular

Hi I have small code snippet in angular 5 project code.

```
this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
      return new FormControl(recipient, this.validators);
    });

    this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
```

here in the code recipients is an array of string . from the code i can see we are itertating through the array , creating a form control . then we are calling updateValueAndValidity(). my question is how is the form control added to the formgroup ??
really appreciate any help

Comment: Where do you think those `FormControl`s are going?

Comment: kindly explain me ? i am bit new to angular 5 . will it get automatically added to the form group when you do a new FormControl ?

Comment: This is firstly a JS question as opposed to an Ng question. `forEach` doesn't directly mutate the array so I'm curious what you think is happening in the sample. If you'd like to get an array of form controls created from the array of strings, consider using `map` instead where the resulting array would be used for the form group.

Comment: true iterating through the array and creating a form control , will not add the form control the form group . yes that is my confusion .  i was thinking it is one of the way to add a form control to the form group in angular or maybe it is a wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supouse you want to say

```
//NOT WORK
myForm=new FormGroup({}) //create a empty formControl
this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
   myForm.addControl("name",new FormControl(recipient, this.validators));
});
```

Well, we need give a "diferent name" so

```
myForm=new FormGroup({}) //create a empty formControl
this.recipients.forEach((recipient,index) => {
   myForm.addControl("name"+index,new FormControl(recipient, this.validators));
});
```

But you can want create a FormArray

```
myFormArray=new FormArray([]) //create a empty formArray
this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
   myForm.push(new FormControl(recipient, this.validators));
});
```

or

```
controls:FormControl[]=[]    //create a empty Array of FormControls
this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
   controls.push(new FormControl(recipient, this.validators));
});
myFormArray=new FormArray(controls) //create a formArray with the controls
```

this last code can be write using "map" (not forEach). "map" return an array "transformed"

```
myFormArray=new FormArray(
     this.recipients.map(recipient => {
            return new FormControl(recipient, this.validators)
     })
);
```